# Better insert option?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, insert

I am dealing with insert just 3 million rows from remote database to local database.

I have tried with

Option 1:

```
insert into lic(field1,field2...field47)
    select * from lic@remote;
```

Option 2:

```
DECLARE
    TYPE T_ARRAY_NUMBER   IS TABLE OF NUMBER ;
    TYPE T_ARRAY_VARCHAR2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(60) ;
    T_ARRAY_FUENTE     T_ARRAY_VARCHAR2 ;
    T_ARRAY_MODULO  T_ARRAY_VARCHAR2 ;

    CURSOR CUR IS
        SELECT FUENTE,MODULO
        FROM LICENCIAS@REMOTE 
        WHERE TO_CHAR(FECHA_PAGO,'yy')='12' and     to_char(fecha_pago,'MM')='02' ;
    BEGIN
        OPEN cur ;
       LOOP

       FETCH CUR BULK COLLECT INTO T_ARRAY_FUENTE , T_ARRAY_MODULO
       LIMIT 100;

       FORALL I IN 1 .. T_ARRAY_FUENTE.COUNT
           INSERT INTO BULK
           VALUES (T_ARRAY_FUENTE(I) , T_ARRAY_MODULO(I)); 

       EXIT WHEN cur%NOTFOUND ;

       END LOOP ;
       COMMIT ;
       CLOSE CUR ;
   END ;
```

Both options are taking too much time.

Any suggestion will be good.

Comment: How is the connection between the two databases?  Fast enough?  What platform are you on?  If it's something Unixy, you might be able to use data pump with named pipes through netcat or something like that.

Comment: Is this one time activity or the part of your application logic. If former you could simply import data using ssms import / export wizard.

Comment: server sql get script for the table. and execute in out local sql

Comment: It is unlikely that there is a more efficient SQL or PL/SQL option than your initial `insert ... select`.  How big is the table, how much bandwidth do you have between the databases, how long is it taking, and how long do you need it to take?  What is the underlying business problem that you are trying to solve?  Is this a one-time requirement or an ongoing requirement?  If it is ongoing, can you use some of the various replication technologies (Streams, materialized views, etc.) to replicate incrementally on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Can you try increasing the BULK collect `LIMIT` to 500 or 1000 ? Also you can try Informatica BI tool if available, Since Informatica users its inbuilt cache

Comment: I am having troubles with the connection @remote database is too slow

Answer (score 0):

Most of the slowness is probably due to sending data over the network, but you could always try adding an append hint to your insert to see if it helps.

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into lic(field1,field2...field47)
    select * from lic@remote;
```